# How do I fscanf data within range only, instead of saving the whole data?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

Basically I have rows and columns of data. I know I can use fgets to read line by line and then tokenise the line with strtok. After that I can check if the last 2 tokens/values are within range using atoi(), and if they are, I can then store them into an array. However, I heard strtok is a bad way to do things, and fscanf seems a much cleaner approach. The problems with fscanf is that if I use it I will have to store all the values in arrays first, and then check which values are within range. Since I have a lot of rows, I don't know how big the arrays should be and it would waste a lot of space. Is there a way to fscanf with if statements?

I don't know if it's a stupid question, thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but can't you just read the data into variables (instead of into the array directly), then do your check and then insert into the array as needed?

Comment: Could you please show a "bad" way of using `fscanf` that works for you? By the way, the only wrong thing about `strtok` is fixed by `strtok_r`.

Comment: I do not think that fscanf is any better than strok. And strok is mainly considered as bad because of it is not "thread safe". But does this matter to you? On the other hand I remember that fscanf has some disadvantages. I would either use the suggested strtok_r or use something different over which you have more control.

Comment: Another appraoch would be to use a standardised file format like JSON for example then you could use an existing parser and care about the more important parts of your program.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight really? `strtok_r` *still* modifies the source string

Comment: Yeah, I haven't thought of that, @jpw you are correct... didn't realize it would be so simple. I am dumb. Sorry.

Comment: I don't think it would matter, as they don't mark efficiency, only the output. But I thought fscanf would be much better, since the prof said it has problems + requires less lines/more readable. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @sehe Modifying the string is not wrong, unless it's unexpected or undocumented. This behavior is easy to explain and to work around, if necessary. Inability to use `strtok` in two nested loops, on the other hand, is just wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you waste it will never exceed the line length. Since yours is clearly a text format, a line length of 1024 is pretty typically the limit¹.

So, in worst case you require (several?) kilobytes of memory to parse each line. You can reuse that buffer and ignore the uninteresting values.

Of course, you can write your own parser and be more memory efficient.

**UPDATE**

There's also this: [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf):

- (optional) assignment-suppressing character `*`. If this option is present, the function does not assign the result of the conversion to any receiving argument.

---

¹ it may vary of course